# Find if this series converges and if so find its value

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I need help I cant understand how we can solve this. I am confused when the log came in. I listed the first few terms but i do not know how to proceed further. all I know is that the sequence is decreasing. A step by step would be great since i am new to this topic.

[image: updated solution]

Comment: Could you please consider using [$\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }(\ln(n+2)-\ln 2)=\lim_{n\to \infty }\ln(1+\frac n2)=+\infty$$

Comment: does that it mean that this series does not have a sum?

Comment: No, it does not converges.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$\ln \left(\dfrac{k+2}{k+1}\right)=\ln (k+2)-\ln(k+1)$$ Now if you expand the sum (as you already have) you will see that this is a telescoping series.

Comment: so can i use telescoping method?

Comment: Yes, that is what you should do.

Comment: can you please feedback to my updates solution

Comment: @Filipos Filipe, look at the other post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985612/summation-of-series-by-telescoping-series-method-feedback-needed/985615#985615, I edited there my answer. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the partial sum:
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \log\left(\frac{k+2}{k+1}\right)
= \left(\sum_{k=3}^{n+2} \log k\right) - \left(\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \log k\right)
= \log(n+2) - \log 2.
$$
Then,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \log(n+2) - \log 2 = +\infty.
$$